# How do we select fragmented indexes from postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, index, fragmentation

Need to select indexes which are fragmented for a certain level. Can someone help me with the query for that?

Comment: What exactly is a "fragmented index"? Are you referring to [index bloat](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance#Index_Bloat)?

Comment: yes. the bloated indexes for a table due to deletion of large number of records. Need to fetch the indexes for a given table which are bloated above 30 % or so.

Comment: Also this given query SELECT * FROM pgstatindex('index_name'); fetches the leaf_fragmentation percentage for a given index. not sure how to use this function to select the indexes for a table with leaf_fragmentation above 30 %

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pgstatindex` from the `pgstattuple` extension to get the leaf fragmentation of all B-tree indexes:

```
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass,
       s.leaf_fragmentation
FROM pg_index AS i
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON i.indexrelid = t.oid
   JOIN pg_opclass AS opc ON i.indclass[0] = opc.oid
   JOIN pg_am ON opc.opcmethod = pg_am.oid
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL pgstatindex(i.indexrelid) AS s
WHERE t.relkind = 'i'
  AND pg_am.amname = 'btree';
```

This will scan through all these indexes and might take a long time.

Note that it is normal for an index to be up to 70% fragmented.